# I would like to call setinterval, and when set interval completes, change the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use set interval, and when interval completes, change page - however, with this below, it changes the page after 1 interval run when I want to to change page when myNumber >= 300.

I'd be grateful of any help, thanks

```
    var myNumber = 0;

function openportal() {

    var myInterval = window.setInterval(myzoom,2);
        document.location.href ="http://next page";

}

function myzoom () {

      if(myNumber>=300){
          clearInterval(myInterval);
      }
      myNumber++;

}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you are running increments of 2 miliseconds in the first place. We might be able to help you with a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you were calling `document.location.href ="http://next page";` in the `openportal` method, which will set the interval and then redirect the page to the new location.

```
var myNumber = 0, myInterval;

function openportal() {
    myInterval = window.setInterval(myzoom,2);    
}

function myzoom () {
    if(myNumber>=300){
        clearInterval(myInterval)
        document.location.href ="http://next page";
    }
    myNumber++;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this is not working, it was what I tried second; putting the page change after the clearinterval, means that the function zoom ends before it gets a chance to change page.

Comment: correction, I just noticed that you had defined myInterval the variable before setting the value; its working now.  thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` method is asynchronous. It doesn't wait for the interval to be stopped.

Change the page where you stop the interval:

```
var myNumber = 0;
var myInterval;

function openportal() {

  myInterval = window.setInterval(myzoom,2);

}

function myzoom () {

  if(myNumber>=300){
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    document.location.href ="http://next page";
  }
  myNumber++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this is not working, it was what I tried second; putting the page change after the clearinterval, means that the function zoom ends before it gets a chance to change page.

Comment: @RozAgnew: It should work just fine. Arun P Johny posted the same code a few minutes later, and you said in a comment that it worked.